# How to create an ordered string from multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I want to create an ordered string column (C4) given the columns C1, C2, and C3, how can I proceed so?

[image]

Comment: You just want to order by column C4?  Then you would just use ORDER BY

Comment: Hello, I would like to alphabetically order the strings within the C4 and NOT order the whole table by the C4.

Comment: SSMS is used by multiple applications, such as SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, and Azure Synapse. What are you actually using? Tagging SSMS is a little like tagging Visual Studio for the programming language.

Comment: SQL Server Manager

Comment: "SQL Server Manager" isnt' an (R)DBMS; there's not even an application with that name.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: That's SSMS... That's explicitly what I told you isn't what we need to know. What (R)DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Azure Synapse? Something else?

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On on the assumption *ssms* indicates you're using SQL Server, you can unpivot your columns and use *string_agg* to concatenate them in order.

An example would be:

```
with data as (
  select * from (values('Alton', 'Webs', 'James'), ('a', 'b', 'c'),('c', 'b', 'a')
)x(c1,c2,c3))
select *
from data
cross apply(
    select String_Agg(c,'') within group(order by c) as c4
    from(
        values(c1),(c2),(c3)
    )s(c)
)c4;
```

Comment: Does concat take care of alphabetical sorting of strings?

Comment: Ah - nope I missed that lol. Will delete and replace with a version that does

Comment: @IsaacA please try the above revised answer